# Keras model erroring when I use Model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, sequential

so I am making an AI to detect descriptions of cats to cat name
But I get this error when I run model.fit

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 2), found shape=(None, 2)
```

(This is my first time researching this stuff so expect it to be a bit wrong)

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('cat.csv')
x = dataset.drop(columns=['href'])
y = dataset['name']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=x_train.shape, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=400)
```

I tried researched this error to no avail, heres my csv file too: https://easyupload.io/c7r9ez

I tried to train the model to get the name of a cat by its description as accurate as possible but when I try to fit the model I get an error.

Comment: The input shape does not contain the samples dimension, so setting it directly to be the training data shape is incorrect.